# How to update an HTML meter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, meter

I want to implement this feature where say a meter is included and basically depending on the option you choose, it fluctuates. So if one goes east and ends up at a store, the meter is say, 30% full. But if they goes west, the meter is like 20%.
How would I be able to incorporate an HTML feature into my JavaScript code? Is there a way where I can solely write HTML in there without disrupting the JavaScript code>

I tried doing 
and then adding a var called meter with a document.getElementById ending in .innerHTML but that didn't seem to work.

Here's the code for west, which doesn't have any other options to choose from as of right now:

JavaScript

```
else if (newInput == "West") {
    textInput = "You went to the abandoned neighborhood";
    //state = "sites"
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = textInput;
}
```

And here's the HTML for the meter that I'd like altered:

```
<p align = "center" id = "meter">
    <font color = "red">
        <b>Awareness:<progress value = "0" max = "100"></b>
    </font>
</p>
```

Thank you for the response!

Comment: I'm really sorry. I honestly don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Make a decision between `"meter"` and `"message"`, and then use consistently.

Comment: @evolutionxbox what I want is a different percentage of the meter full depending on the options one chooses to go. So for this example, if one typed in west, the meter will be displayed a certain percentage. I would like to know how to make that work

Comment: A couple things. Pleas stop using `<font>`. Is it `message` or `meter`? Why is `<progress>` being used when `<meter>` [exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meter)? Have you tried editing the `value` property of the `<progress>` element? May you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry, my bad it's a progress bar. I gave the progress bar the id of "meter". Message is from a previous id I'm using, it doesn't have anything to do with the progress bar.

Comment: Ten  If you want to manipulate the progress bar with help of javascript this code will help

1. provide a id to <progress /> element e.g: file

2.  var z = document.getElementById('file');
    z.value =80;// you can manipulate the value

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!